# constructing sub-dataframes with iteration

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe 1000 X 10.

One column, has 6 unique numeric values

```
df['column'].value_counts() = [ 0,2,5,8,9,10]
```

I would like to automate a process, probably an iteration, which would do the following:

For every unique value of the column, to create a smaller dataset, containing all the rows, that have this unique value in that column.In my case, 6 smaller datasets, for every one of the unique values

I know how to do it without an iteration. For instance

```
df_0 = df[df['column'] == 0]

df_1 = df[df['column'] == 1]
```

But how can I automate it?

I thought about sth like

```
for value in df['column'].value_counts():
    df_value = df[df['column'] == value]
```

but it just functions only for the first value and stops.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do what you want with python and pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {1: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1]}
data.update({val: range(10) for val in range(2, 101)})
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print('df_shape =', df.shape)

for value in sorted(df[1].unique()):
    sub_df = df[df[1] == value]
    print(
        'value = {}, sub_df_shape = {}'
        .format(value, sub_df.shape))
```

Output:

```
df_shape = (10, 100)
value = 1, sub_df_shape = (3, 100)
value = 2, sub_df_shape = (2, 100)
value = 3, sub_df_shape = (2, 100)
value = 4, sub_df_shape = (1, 100)
value = 5, sub_df_shape = (1, 100)
value = 6, sub_df_shape = (1, 100)
```

**EDIT**

You can can get access to sub-dataframes anytime. If you still want to store sub-dataframes in some separate variable you may use dictionary:

```
ans = dict()
for value in sorted(df[1].unique()):
    ans[value] = df[df[1] == value]
```

You can even create separate variable for every sub-dataframe (although it is something wierd and I would avoid to do this under any circumstances):

```
for value in sorted(df[1].unique()):
    sub_df = df[df[1] == value]
    exec('df_{} = sub_df'.format(value))
```

Comment: tnx, but what i need is an iteration that will construct 6 new dataframes, with very similar names. like df_0 , df_1 ,df_5, df_8,df_9,df_10. I mean that i want a way to incorporate into the df name, the values of the value_counts() operation, one after the other.

Comment: @apostolos I have edited the answer according to your comment.